# PHP Acessing remote script with directory authentication

Tags: php, curl, proxy

i'm trying to access a remote script using curl.

Normally is not a problem, just do curl_init, set some option and do curl_exec. Simple enough.

Now some complication.

The remote script is an ASP script placed in a folder protected by http authentication under Microsoft IIS.

My script is a PHP script free for all under apache.

After tre days of tests the problem is clearly the authentication.

What i tryed already is to puth authentication in the host like

```
http://user:pass@myHost.com/stupidFolder/myUnreachableScript.asp
```

and also

```
$user_pass = $_SESSION['user'] . ":" . $_SESSION['pass']; 
curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user_pass );
curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY );
```

i use to store user and password in session becuase someone told me to resend credential each call once login happen.

what i get in response from curl?

```
401 Unauthorized... and the script i'm looking for.
```

The problem is that browser think i cannot access and prompt me for user and password again

There is some other way to pass credential?
is this a problem from IIS behavior?

Any other idea?

Any help will be appreciated

regards

EDIT: this is the response header i get

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 2112
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="myHost.com"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 03 Sep 2014 08:22:12 GMT
Connection: close

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 03 Sep 2014 08:22:12 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 2900
Content-Type: text/html
Cache-control: private
```

edit 2 curl code:

the following snippet is part of a singleton class and appen when the system call the url. Sorry for italian comments :p

$instance is the local instance of the singleton and i use a variable instead this because the method is a class method

```
    $curlSession = curl_init( );

    $instance->log( "Inizio Forward verso [".$url."]" );

    curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    //work out cookie domain
    $cookiedomain = str_replace("http://www.","",$base);
    $cookiedomain = str_replace("https://www.","",$cookiedomain);
    $cookiedomain = str_replace("www.","",$cookiedomain);

    // IMPOSTO GLI HEADERS
    curl_setopt( $curlSession, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $_localHeaders );
    curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $instance->log( "Trovato Method POST: ".http_build_query( $_POST ) );
        curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $_POST ) );
    }

    if ( $instance->_forwardOptions == null ) {
        self::setForwardOptions( );
    }

    // salvo le credenziali nella curl opt se ci sono
    if( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) )
    {
        $instance->log( "ABEMUS SESSION USER!!!!! ".$_SESSION['user'] );
        // se mi hanno passato delle credenziali le aggiungo all'url
        $user_pass = $_SESSION['user'] . ":" . $_SESSION['pass'];
        curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user_pass );
        curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY );
    }

    curl_setopt_array( $curlSession, $instance->_forwardOptions );
    // IMPOSTO I COOKIES
    foreach( $_localCookies as $k=>$v ){
        if( is_array( $v ) )
        {
            $v = serialize( $v );
        }
        curl_setopt($curlSession,CURLOPT_COOKIE,$k."=".$v."; domain=.".$cookiedomain." ; path=/");
        $instance->log( "Invio richiesta con cookie $k valore $v" );
    }

    $response = curl_exec ($curlSession);
```

and now the method setForwardOptions. This method just provide a config point for the class

```
public static function setForwardOptions( $options = null )
{
    $instance = self::getInstance();
    if ( $options == null ) {
        $instance->_forwardOptions = array(
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 0,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 1,
            CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $instance->_cookiefile,
            CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $instance->_cookiefile
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the complete `curl` script you have?

Comment: is a bit complex since is inside a class with 470 rows inside !! I'll try to post the essentials